# jQuery: Get Class Name and Manipulate String

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Trying to solve this problem:

I have the following set of divs that when clicked show a particular panel. I can do this by hard coding the values, but was wondering how to go about this in the most efficient way.

```
<div id="myContainer">
<div id="myMenu_1" class="myMenu">Menu1</div>
<div id="myMenu_2" class="myMenu">Menu2</div>
<div id="myMenu_3" class="myMenu">Menu3</div>
</div>

<div id="myPanel_1" class="myPanel">If Menu1 is clicked show this panel</div>
<div id="myPanel_2" class="myPanel">If Menu2 is clicked show this panel</div>
<div id="myPanel_3" class="myPanel">If Menu3 is clicked show this panel</div>
```

As noted above, I know how to do this by

```
$('myMenu_1').click(function(){$('myPanel_3').hide();$('myPanel_2').hide();$('myPanel_1').show();});
```

But this doesn't seem very efficient if I have to do it for multiple items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work with an arbitrary number of `<div>`s:

```
$("div.myMenu").click(function() {
  $("div.myPanel").hide();
  var index = $(this).attr("id").split("_")[1];
  $("div#myPanel_" + index).show();
});
```

Comment: ah yes, that makes sense... will accept in 8 min. thanks paul!

Comment: Paul, any idea why this wouldn't show the panel until the second click? Having issues here :(

Comment: Please link to the page with the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide all of them with prefix selector,
and then show only the required one. that would make your code simpler and shorter.

Something like this, forgive any errors, I did not test this, and I am not fluent in jQuery.

```
   $('[id$=foo]')
    $('[^id=myMenu').click(
    function(){ $([^id=myPanel).hide(); // hide all panels 
                 var toShowId = $(this).attr('id').replace("myMenu","myPanel");
                 $('#'+toShowId).show(); // show corresponding panel .
     }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('myMenu_1').click(function() { 
    $("div[id^='myPanel_']").hide(); 
});
```